# Check if navigation.navigate is called in react native testing

Tags: react-native, testing

I've been using 'react-test-renderer' for testing react-native, Mostly on it's functions. Lately I've found out that there is a testing library for react-native which is @testing-library/react-native. What I wanted to do is to check if navigation.navigate or alert has been called in a function. I don't know which of these libraries can achieve that and how.

```
onSubmitPress = () => {
  if (true) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('MainPage');
  else { 
     showAlert( "Not Allowed);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'react-test-renderer':

like this:

```js
const fakeNavigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),

};
const tree = renderer.create(

        <YourComponent navigation={fakeNavigation}  />

    );
```

after that you can use jest `expect` function to test if mock `navigation.navigate` is called someThing like this:

```js
const instance = tree.getInstance();
instance.onSubmit();
expect(fakeNavigation.navigate).toBeCalledWith('MainPage')
```

for `react-native-testing-library` it's a bit different as you test mostly what user sees depending of the behavior of your component.

Basically you look for your button that calls onSubmit and then use `fireEvent` from `react-native-testing-library` to `press` it, after that you expect the text of your alert to be shown in screen or not.

If you have a button like this in your component=

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
 <Text>Submit</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can test the behavior of you function like this:

```js
const {getByText} = render(<YourComponent/>)
let buttonText = getByText('Submit');
fireEvent(buttonText.parent, 'press'); //parent to get to TouchableOpacity
alertText = getByText('Not Allowed');
expect(alertText).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: const tree = render( 
        <YourComponent navigation={fakeNavigation}  />   
        tree.onSubmitPress()
        //code for expect
    );
is this right?

Comment: I'm sorry this way is more for `react-test-renderer`, i will change the answer, `react-native-testing-library` is more testing what the user can see on screen